# Why MPMusicPlayerController MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification called twice?

Tags: ios, notifications, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using following code for playing a song from device. I added notification for **MPMusicPlayerController** to recognize state of the player.

```
 self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]; 
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handlePlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.musicPlayer]; 
 [self.musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications]; 
 [self.musicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
```

Following method is called twice when musicplayer satrts playing the song.

```
 -(void)handlePlaybackStateChanged :(id )notification
```

My question why its called twice? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check the function that this is in is not being called twice and try logging the notification and adding breakpoints to figure out when it is being called.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to solve the same thing now. Here is what I found; `handlePlaybackStateChanged` is called when the `currentPlaybackRate` is 0 (stopped) or 1 (playing).  When hitting the nextSong button it stops the current song then plays the next song, thus it fires twice. My code below has been cleaned up and it's in Swift but you should get my point.

```
func handle_PlaybackStateChanged(){
    println("handle_PlaybackStateChanged")

    if player.currentPlaybackRate == 0{
        println("playbackStatePause0")
    }else{
        println("playbackStatePause1")
    }
}
```

The output between songs is

```
handle_PlaybackStateChanged
playbackStatePause0
handle_PlaybackStateChanged
playbackStatePause1
```